# Software to animate and create a 3D Model for Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, modeling

I just wanted to ask if there is any kind of program, where you can create a 3D Model and also animate it and use it for a game engine like Unity.

Comment: Blender, Maya or 3dsMax.

Comment: @Programmer And which one would you recommend best? (not about pricing)

Comment: Your question as asked is "off-topic." Rephrased as your comment, it is "primarily opinion based." Both are reasons for closure.

Comment: Okay anyway thanks for your help !

Comment: Note that this question belongs to gamedev or software recommendation site. This site is for programming questions. If not about pricing then Maya. I say this because of the amount of support it has for Unity like PBR shader, character bones, and the ability to update your models from Maya without re-exporting them back and forth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to use free software, you can choose Blender. Blender has a ton of tutorials and a thriving community.

If you're a student, you can get free licence for Maya, 3dsMax and ZBrush.
Maya, 3dsMax and Blender is more convenient for tech objects like robots, cars etc.
ZBrush is more convenient for organic objects.

You can use ZBrush for sculpting characters; Blender, 3dsMax, Maya for environment things.

What to use in your case is up to you.